# Open source 3D imageviewer for Multi Picture Object (.mpo) files (Linux)

Tags: linux, open-source, photography, 3d

Multi Picture Object (.mpo) files with two embedded .jpeg files can be displayed with geeqie. But it shows only the two plain jpeg files.

Which open source image viewer can show `.mpo` images with a 3D effect (red/green, stereoscopic, or other technology)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This programs can show mpo files in defferent formats:

- https://stereophotoview.bitbucket.io/en/
- http://www.sview.ru/en/

Answer (score 3):

A quick search does not present any results for a viewer to display .MPO files in anaglyph form. This would be due to the original method of creation. The .MPO type was created to accept images generated by dual-lens cameras or the equivalent, which of course, would not have red/green or red/blue capability.

If you use a "standard" viewer for .MPO files, which display the image in left/right format, it is stereoscopic but only if you use a split-lens type viewer. The software will not generate a stereoscopic image viewable by unaided eyeballs.

I suppose one could stretch the reasoning a bit and create an image format that would be viewable on the niche-market 3D tablets and/or televisions, but that's certainly not the scope of your question.

By searching for "convert .MPO to anaglyph" I located a number of programs that will take the dual images and color-convert them to the typical red/green or red/blue anaglyph you seek.

These are not viewers, per se, but may be the only option available to you, considering the constraints inherent in the .MPO file format.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu you can use `exiftool` to extract the two images:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
exiftool -b -mpimage2 input.mpo > left.jpg
exiftool -trailer:all= input.mpo -o right.jpg
```

(See [here](http://www.noah.org/wiki/ImageMagick#split_MPO_stereo_3D_images_into_component_stereo_pairs) for further details.)

You can then use ImageMagick's `composite` tool to join the two together as an anaglyph. I'm not sure if you would be best converting the pair to greyscale first:

```
composite left.jpg right.jpg -stereo 10 stereo.jpg
```

See [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23204) for some discussion.

I'm pleased to see that a long established GUI tool called Stereo Photo Viewer is open source. The Bitbucket webpage is [here](https://stereophotoview.bitbucket.io/en), and the repo itself is [here](https://bitbucket.org/stereophotoview/stereophotoview). It is an editor and a viewer.